# How to slice middle three element from list in python3

Tags: python-3.x, slice

how we can find the middle three element in the list?

```
players = ["micheal", "eli", "john", "watson", "messi"]
```

Comment: We didn't understand the question, please post with example

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're asking:

```py
players = ["micheal", "eli", "john", "watson", "messi"]
players[1:-1]

#['eli', 'john', 'watson']
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not the prettiest solution but u can try using the `len()` function.

`new_list = players[int(len(players)/2-1) : int(len(players)/2+2)]`

Answer (score 0):

players = ["micheal", "eli", "john", "watson", "messi1", "messi","messi"]

```
if len(players)//2:
    #for even number in list
    ref = int(len(players)/2)
    players = players[ref-2:ref+1]

else:
    #odd number in list
     ref = int((len(players)-1)/2)
    players = players[ref-1:ref+2]
```